# How to change variable to circumvent inline javascript window.onload timer in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, timer, tampermonkey

I have tried to used Tampermonkey 4.5.5663 in Chrome Version 63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit) to circumvent the following javascript in the HEAD section of a website page which does not allow going to the next page until the timer hits zero:

```
<!-- COUNTDOWN TIMER --> 
<script language=JavaScript type=text/javascript> 
<!-- 
 var sec=96; 
 function countDown() {
     sec--;
     time=sec+' sec '; 
     if (document.getElementById) {
         document.getElementById('Timer').innerHTML=time; 
     } 
     SD = window.setTimeout('countDown();', 1000); 
     if ( sec == 00) {
         sec = 00; window.clearTimeout(SD); 
     }
 } 
 window.onload = countDown; 
 // --> 
 </script>
```

In Tampermonkey, I tried:

```
countDown = null;
```

and put // in front of the function lines of the Tampermonkey boilerplate code.
I am ok with using Tampermonkey, and am completely open to other solutions.
This inline webpage timer is a huge waste of time for me and I want to defeat it and to move at my own pace. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated...
   Rexie

Comment: `00` is not a valid number. Have you tried `sec = 1`?

Comment: The Javascript source posted above is from the head of the webpage itself.  Is there a way to get Tampermonkey to modify the variable sec?  Or maybe a way to get the window.clearTimeout(SD) to go to zero before or after the page loads?

Comment: Does the tampermonkey script run before or after this script?

Comment: Looking in the developer console, it does appear to be running after the inline javascript of the page.

Answer (score 0):

If the tampermonkey script runs after the script from the page, a simple `sec = 1;` will work. Setting it to 0 will not work and it will count to the negatives infinitely.

If, however, your script runs before the script from the page, you can try this slightly ugly approach:

```
const oldTimeout = window.setTimeout;
window.setTimeout = function(cb, time) {
    if (cb === 'countDown();') {
        time = 0;
    }
    return oldTimeout(cb, time);
}
```

Comment: Just tried [code]// ==UserScript==
// ALL OF MY ampersand parts here (StackOverflow thinks they are references to users)
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    sec = 1;

})();[code] But no success.Tried [code]// ==UserScript==
// ALL OF MY ampersand details here 
// ==/UserScript==

const oldTimeout = window.setTimeout;
window.setTimeout = function(cb, time) {
        'use strict';
    if (cb === 'countDown();') {
        time = 0;
    }
    return oldTimeout(cb, time);
};

[code]  before that and same issue.  What am I misunderstanding?